# Ceiling not working properly in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014, ceil

Used below expression to show only 50 Rows per page.

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/50)
```

But still it shows only 42 rows per page. Crystal report shows perfectly fine but SSRS report doesn't.

[image]
*Please help me to solve my problem!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from [**here**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3023/sql-server-reporting-services-tips-and-tricks-to-improve-the-end-user-experience/),

Need to set the Interactive Height property of the report to zero as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I was not able to find out the issue after using `Ceiling` - if it is not correct then let me know if I need to change my subject... I will change

Comment: @pedram Glad this helped you. Just to clarify; this removes the paging in the report viewer, but would have no effect on an exported version of the report.

Comment: I have checked now, it shows paging perfectly. but while exporting to pdf it breaks the page.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is within Visual Studio at the moment?

Delete the *report_name*.data file so that the report is not cached.

Comment: Yes, m using VS. But where can I find this file. As I am directly calling this report from my report server.

Comment: 1. How?
2. While answering that can you also delete the .data file from the same location as your .rdl file on (probably) your local PC.

Comment: 1. By making report server url I am accessing it from report viewer to show. 2. I don't think it will saved to my pc.

Comment: Nope. accessing local report.

Comment: Tell me the path that you are opening the rdl from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110958/discussion-between-pedram-and-bideveloper).

Answer (score 0):

Set the “`BreakLocation`” to “`End`” and set the “`Disable`” property to the expression below:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 50 = 0, False, True)
```

Comment: now it shows 45 rows instead of 42. also let me tell you one more thing, when I use 40 instead of 50 it works perfectly fine so I checked my design part but it seems to correct. I have used SizeToReportContent = true.

Comment: also when go to next page is show other 5 records, so 45 + 5 and then 3rd page with 46 rows and 4th page with 4 rows. :(

Comment: @pedram You're getting actual page breaks confused with pages in the report viewer. If you export this to Word or Excel, the page breaks will occur every 50 lines. If they don't fit on the page, that's a separate issue.